# Tokio FramedRead.for_each called indefinitely for single response

Tags: unix, rust, future, codec, rust-tokio

I've been mucking with tokio for a few weeks in the pursuit of writing a protocol using tokio_uds. There are several issues with the following code:

`framed.for_each` is called over and over from a single response.

The socket only sends 1 real message, but the `Decoder` decodes the exact same event as many times as it can until it fills up the bounded channel.

Nothing is ever received over the channel (`rx.for_each` never prints anything), though it appears to be written until it fills up.

I need to use a UnixStream and not a UnixListener because there's some data I must put over the socket first to 'subscribe' to the service and let it know what to send.

```rust
use byteorder::{ByteOrder, LittleEndian};
use bytes::{Buf, BufMut, Bytes, BytesMut, IntoBuf};
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender};
use futures::Stream;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio_codec::{Decoder, Encoder, FramedRead};
use tokio_uds::UnixStream;

fn subscribe(tx: Sender<event::Evt>, events: Vec<Event>) -> io::Result<()> {
    let fut = UnixStream::connect(socket_path()?)
        .and_then(move |stream| {
            // some setup
            tokio::io::write_all(stream, buf)
        })
        .and_then(|(stream, _buf)| {
            let buf = [0_u8; 30]; // <i3-ipc (6 bytes)><len (4 bytes)><type (4 bytes)><{success:true} 16 bytes>
            tokio::io::read_exact(stream, buf)
        })
        .and_then(|(stream, initial)| {
            if &initial[0..6] != MAGIC.as_bytes() {
                panic!("Magic str not received");
            }
            // decoding initial response and returning stream
            future::ok(stream)
        })
        .and_then(move |stream| {
            let framed = FramedRead::new(stream, EvtCodec);
            let sender = framed
                .for_each(move |evt| {
                    let tx = tx.clone();
                    tx.send(evt).wait(); // this line is called continuously until buffer fills
                    Ok(())
                })
                .map_err(|err| println!("{}", err));
            tokio::spawn(sender);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map(|_| ())
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("{:?}", e));

    tokio::run(fut);
    Ok(())
}

    fn test_sub() -> io::Result<()> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(5);
        subscribe(tx, vec![Event::Window])?;
        let fut = rx.for_each(|e: event::Evt| {
            println!("received"); // never reaches
            future::ok(())
        });
        tokio::spawn(fut);
        Ok(())
    }
```

My `Decoder`:

```rust
pub struct EvtCodec;

/// decoding: "<i3-ipc><payload len: u32><msg type: u32><payload>"
impl Decoder for EvtCodec {
    type Item = event::Evt;
    type Error = io::Error;
    fn decode(&mut self, src: &mut BytesMut) -> Result<Option<Self::Item>, io::Error> {
        if src.len() > 14 {
            if &src[0..6] != MAGIC.as_bytes() {
                return Err(io::Error::new(
                    io::ErrorKind::Other,
                    format!("Expected 'i3-ipc' but received: {:?}", &src[0..6]),
                ));
            }
            let payload_len = LittleEndian::read_u32(&src[6..10]) as usize;
            let evt_type = LittleEndian::read_u32(&src[10..14]);
            dbg!(&src.len()); // 878
            dbg!(payload_len); // 864
            if src.len() < 14 + payload_len {
                Ok(None)
            } else {
                let evt = decode_evt(evt_type, src[14..].as_mut().to_vec())?;
                dbg!(&evt); // correctly prints out a well-formed event
                Ok(Some(evt))
            }
        } else {
            Ok(None)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience, I've had to clear the decoder buffer once I pass back some piece of data. Otherwise Decoder thinks it didn't receive all of the data needed to decode. Have you tried doing like a src.clear() before returning Ok(Some(evt))?

Comment: Wow! that appeared to fix the first part of the issue, where I would get the same frame over and over again. Any ideas why the receiving end of my channel isn't getting any data? (rx.for_each....)

edit: if you have any ideas for that and you want to write it as an answer along with the `src.clear()` tip, i'll be happy to accept that as an answer

Comment: I got the receiving end working, it had something to do with the way futures were being spawned. My suspicion is that the Receiver and Sender are running in different instances of tokio in my test harness. I was able to rectify that by passing a handle to `subscribe`

If you'd like to submit your first bit about src.clear() as a solution I'll select it as an answer, I think it could be helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you resolved your other issue, and I'd be really interested to see how you solved this problem. Here's how I fixed it on my TCP Tokio side project:

```
use byteorder::{ByteOrder, LittleEndian};
use bytes::{Buf, BufMut, Bytes, BytesMut, IntoBuf};
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender};
use futures::Stream;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio_codec::{Decoder, Encoder, FramedRead};
use tokio_uds::UnixStream;

fn subscribe(tx: Sender<event::Evt>, rx: Receiver<event::Evt>, events: Vec<Event>) -> io::Result<()> {
    let fut = UnixStream::connect(socket_path()?)
        .and_then(move |stream| {
            // some setup
            tokio::io::write_all(stream, buf)
        })
        .and_then(|(stream, _buf)| {
            let buf = [0_u8; 30]; // <i3-ipc (6 bytes)><len (4 bytes)><type (4 bytes)><{success:true} 16 bytes>
            tokio::io::read_exact(stream, buf)
        })
        .and_then(|(stream, initial)| {
            if &initial[0..6] != MAGIC.as_bytes() {
                panic!("Magic str not received");
            }
            // decoding initial response and returning stream
            future::ok(stream)
        })
        .and_then(move |stream| {
            let framed = FramedRead::new(stream, EvtCodec);
            let (writer, reader) = framed.split();

            // Connect your framed reader to the channel
            let sink = rx.forward(writer.sink_map_err(|_| ()));
            tokio::spawn(sink.map(|_| ()));

            let sender = reader
                .for_each(move |evt| {
                    let tx = tx.clone();
                    tx.send(evt).wait(); // this line is called continuously until buffer fills
                    Ok(())
                })
                .map_err(|err| println!("{}", err));
            tokio::spawn(sender);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map(|_| ())
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("{:?}", e));

    tokio::run(fut);
    Ok(())
}

    fn test_sub() -> io::Result<()> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(5);
        subscribe(tx, rx, vec![Event::Window])?;
        let fut = rx.for_each(|e: event::Evt| {
            println!("received"); // never reaches
            future::ok(())
        });
        tokio::spawn(fut);
        Ok(())
    }
```

And the Decoder with the buffer clear:

```
pub struct EvtCodec;

/// decoding: "<i3-ipc><payload len: u32><msg type: u32><payload>"
impl Decoder for EvtCodec {
    type Item = event::Evt;
    type Error = io::Error;
    fn decode(&mut self, src: &mut BytesMut) -> Result<Option<Self::Item>, io::Error> {
        if src.len() > 14 {
            if &src[0..6] != MAGIC.as_bytes() {
                return Err(io::Error::new(
                    io::ErrorKind::Other,
                    format!("Expected 'i3-ipc' but received: {:?}", &src[0..6]),
                ));
            }
            let payload_len = LittleEndian::read_u32(&src[6..10]) as usize;
            let evt_type = LittleEndian::read_u32(&src[10..14]);
            dbg!(&src.len()); // 878
            dbg!(payload_len); // 864
            if src.len() < 14 + payload_len {
                Ok(None)
            } else {
                let evt = decode_evt(evt_type, src[14..].as_mut().to_vec())?;
                dbg!(&evt); // correctly prints out a well-formed event
                src.clear(); // Clears the buffer, so you don't have to keep decoding the same packet over and over.
                Ok(Some(evt))
            }
        } else {
            Ok(None)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

According to a user on the rust subreddit that commented after I included this solution in a blog post, `src.clear()` is probably the wrong answer for me. I should instead be using `src.advance(14+payload_len)

linking the reddit comment [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/bb7m1u/protocols_in_tokio_i3_ipc/ekh9rnq/)

Comment: I fixed the other issue by using tokio::current_thread::Runtime to get a runtime reference, then passed that Handle to my subscribe function and used it to spawn() the for_each future that was processing the frames. And also used the same handle to spawn() the rx.for_each that was the receiving end of the mpsc::channel. If that makes any sense. I think the issue was it was running in a different tokio context. Thanks again for your help.